# How do I read unknown post data with Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, post, sinatra

Say I've got that application that stores it's settings in a database.

For modifying settings, I just print each setting into a form using slim:

Sinatra part:

```
get '/settings' do
  @settings = Setting.all
  slim :showsettings
end
```

Slim part:

```
@@ showsettings
h1 Settings
form action="/settings" method="POST"
  table
    - @settings.each do |setting|
      tr
        td
          label for="#{setting.name}" #{setting.name}
        td
          input type="text" name="#{setting.name}" value="#{setting.value}"
  input.button type="submit" value="Update Settings"
```

When I submit the form, I get back to `/settings` and want to process the POST request. I know that all of the parameters are stored in the `params` variable.

If I print params, I receive the following string:

```
["name1", "value1"]["name2", "value2"]["name3", "value3"]["name4", "value4"]
```

**How do I process all of the submitted parameters when I don't know how they are named?** Of course, I could hard-code the parameter names into the code but this would be hard to maintain.

---

**Edit:**
What I'm basically looking for is something like the `keys` function in Perl which I could use for something like `for my $key ( keys %hash )`...

Comment: it's a bit difficult to process what you don't know

Comment: If I got a hash in Perl, I could also walk over it using `for my $key ( keys %hash )`. I'm looking for a similar thing here. I just want to take all the parameters and store them back into the database...

Comment: with `ActiveRecord` you can actually do something like `Klass.create(params)` with `params` being a hash, however you need to be sure that the content of the hash is safe

Comment: @bjhaid: see my own answer and the comment on it. Its easy if you know how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the entries in a Hash directly with [`each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-each), you don’t necessarily need to use `keys`:

```
post '/settings' do
  params.each do |key, value|
    Setting.get(key).update(:value => value)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Found it myself:

```
post '/settings' do
  params.keys.each do |key|
    s = Setting.get(key)
    s.update( :value => params[key])
  end
end
```

Comment: You don’t necessarily need to use `keys`, you can iterate over each key -> value pair with [`Hash#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-each): `params.each do |key, value| ...`, then when updating `s.update(:value => value)`.

Comment: @matt: Post this as an answer and you'll get rep from me :-)